# (still) cannot properly install lxml 2.3 for python, but at least 2.2.8 works

Tags: python, linux, makefile, centos, lxml

- *30 jun 2011* -- I am awarding @Pablo for this question, because of his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417881/updated-29-june-still-cannot-properly-install-lxml-for-python/6523725#6523725). 
  I am still unable to properly install lxml 2.3 for reasons discussed in his comments. I gather for a little bit of work I could, but I have already spent a ridiculous amount of time on this problem. I have, however, written the code I needed and successfully installed lxml 2.2.8. The code functions with this version. Better yet, Pablo was the only one to properly diagnose the error. Which was libxslt needed to be updated to a version with support for `exsltMathXpathCtxtRegister` I appreciate everyones help on this question.
- *29 jun 2011 -- updating this question to reflect comments and to greater document my attempts*

---

I should begin by saying I have tried every possible solution and install scenario imaginable. Yes, there are similar questions with this topic but their specific problem and solution are not my own. I have spent about 10-15 hours on this and I only continue to become more perplexed.

**My Main Concern**

In short, after installing lxml-2.3 from source **or** with `easy_install-2.7 lxml` for python2.7 on centOs5.6, an alternate install of python, I cannot import the module properly. It will install without any obvious error, but It returns the following error when trying to import etree:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 16 2011, 11:53:48) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: exsltMathXpathCtxtRegister
```

**What I have Tried**

1. The two most common suggestions I have encountered are to make sure `libxml2 && libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1 && libxslt1-dev`They are. I have installed them through yum.

   > $ yum list libxslt libxslt-devel libxml2
   >   libxml2-devel Loaded plugins:
   >   fastestmirror Installed Packages
   >   libxml2.i386
   >   2.6.26-2.1.2.8.el5_5.1                           installed libxml2.x86_64
   >   2.6.26-2.1.2.8.el5_5.1                           installed libxml2-devel.i386
   >   2.6.26-2.1.2.8.el5_5.1                           installed libxml2-devel.x86_64
   >   2.6.26-2.1.2.8.el5_5.1                           installed libxslt.i386
   >   1.1.17-2.el5_2.2                                 installed libxslt.x86_64
   >   1.1.17-2.el5_2.2                                 installed libxslt-devel.i386
   >   1.1.17-2.el5_2.2                                 installed libxslt-devel.x86_64
   >   1.1.17-2.el5_2.2                                 installed
2. Re-installed and Confirmed that `zlib && zlib-devel` are installed.

   > $ yum list zlib zlib-devel Loaded
   >   plugins: fastestmirror Installed
   >   Packages zlib.i386
   >   1.2.3-3                                    installed zlib.x86_64
   >   1.2.3-3                                    installed zlib-devel.i386
   >   1.2.3-3                                    installed zlib-devel.x86_64
   >   1.2.3-3                                    installed
3. Confirmed `python-devel` is installed. I think.

   a. According to several things I have read a way to check if python-devel is installed is to `import distutils`. regoogling this question brings [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Install_Guide#Install_Python) up quickly.

   b. @Keith suggested I tried to 'install' it anyhow, using [this](ftp://ftp.pycopia.org/pub/python/RHEL51/python2.7-2.7.1-1TH.src.rpm), however, I encountered an error

   ```
       > error: cannot create %sourcedir /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES
   ```

   so, I created the dir, and it has since installed. But with no success.
4. I can, however, `import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree` and/or `import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree`, but I do require some specific functionality from `lxml.etree`
5. Oddly, If I try to install lxml under the assumption the dependencies not installed and try something like the following

   `sudo STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install-2.7 lxml 2>&1 | tee -a ~/.lxml`

   it fails with the outputting the error below. I should tersely note, for the unfamiliar, this seems to solve many people's issues as it will go out and retrieve any dependencies and install them for install lxml.

   `tail -100 ~/.lxml`

   > gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include
   >   -I./include  -D_REENTRANT    -I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include
   >   -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -c runsuite.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
   >   -I./include -I./include  -D_REENTRANT    -I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include
   >   -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -c testchar.c testapi.c: In function
   >   ‘test_xmlBufferSetAllocationScheme’:
   >   testapi.c:18773: warning: comparison
   >   of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
   >   gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include
   >   -I./include  -D_REENTRANT    -I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include
   >   -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -c testdict.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
   >   -I./include -I./include  -D_REENTRANT    -I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include
   >   -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -c runxmlconf.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
   >   -I./include -I./include  -D_REENTRANT    -I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include
   >   -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -c testrecurse.c sed -e
   >   's?\@XML_LIBDIR\@?-L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib?g'
   >   \
   >         -e 's?\@XML_INCLUDEDIR\@?-I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/include?g'
   >   \
   >         -e 's?\@VERSION\@?2.7.8?g' \
   >         -e 's?\@XML_LIBS\@?-lxml2 -lz  -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm ?g' \
   >            < ./xml2Conf.sh.in > xml2Conf.tmp \  && mv xml2Conf.tmp
   >   xml2Conf.sh /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC
   >   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -module -no-undefined -avoid-version -rpath /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib  -o testdso.la  testdso.lo   testapi.c: At top level: testapi.c:17989:
   >   warning: ‘gen_xmlSchematronPtr’
   >   defined but not used testapi.c:17992:
   >   warning: ‘des_xmlSchematronPtr’
   >   defined but not used testapi.c:18009:
   >   warning:
   >   ‘gen_xmlSchematronParserCtxtPtr’
   >   defined but not used testapi.c:18012:
   >   warning:
   >   ‘des_xmlSchematronParserCtxtPtr’
   >   defined but not used testapi.c:34157:
   >   warning: ‘gen_xmlSAXHandlerPtr_ptr’
   >   defined but not used testapi.c:34160:
   >   warning: ‘des_xmlSAXHandlerPtr_ptr’
   >   defined but not used libtool: link: ar
   >   cru .libs/testdso.a  testdso.o
   >   libtool: link: ranlib .libs/testdso.a
   >   libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f
   >   "testdso.la" && ln -s "../testdso.la"
   >   "testdso.la" ) /bin/sh ./libtool
   >   --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls  -version-info 9:8:7 -ldl  -o libxml2.la -rpath
   >   /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib SAX.lo entities.lo encoding.lo
   >   error.lo parserInternals.lo parser.lo
   >   tree.lo hash.lo list.lo xmlIO.lo
   >   xmlmemory.lo uri.lo valid.lo xlink.lo
   >   HTMLparser.lo HTMLtree.lo debugXML.lo
   >   xpath.lo xpointer.lo xinclude.lo
   >   nanohttp.lo nanoftp.lo DOCBparser.lo
   >   catalog.lo globals.lo threads.lo
   >   c14n.lo xmlstring.lo xmlregexp.lo
   >   xmlschemas.lo xmlschemastypes.lo
   >   xmlunicode.lo xmlreader.lo relaxng.lo
   >   dict.lo SAX2.lo xmlwriter.lo legacy.lo
   >   chvalid.lo pattern.lo xmlsave.lo
   >   xmlmodule.lo schematron.lo -lz
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm   libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libxml2.a  SAX.o entities.o
   >   encoding.o error.o parserInternals.o
   >   parser.o tree.o hash.o list.o xmlIO.o
   >   xmlmemory.o uri.o valid.o xlink.o
   >   HTMLparser.o HTMLtree.o debugXML.o
   >   xpath.o xpointer.o xinclude.o
   >   nanohttp.o nanoftp.o DOCBparser.o
   >   catalog.o globals.o threads.o c14n.o
   >   xmlstring.o xmlregexp.o xmlschemas.o
   >   xmlschemastypes.o xmlunicode.o
   >   xmlreader.o relaxng.o dict.o SAX2.o
   >   xmlwriter.o legacy.o chvalid.o
   >   pattern.o xmlsave.o xmlmodule.o
   >   schematron.o libtool: link: ranlib
   >   .libs/libxml2.a libtool: link: ( cd
   >   ".libs" && rm -f "libxml2.la" && ln -s
   >   "../libxml2.la" "libxml2.la" ) /bin/sh
   >   ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc 
   >   -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls   -o xmllint xmllint.o ./libxml2.la  -lz
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm   /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls   -o xmlcatalog xmlcatalog.o ./libxml2.la 
   >   -lz -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm   /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls   -o testSchemas testSchemas.o ./libxml2.la
   >   -lz -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm   /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls   -o testRelax testRelax.o ./libxml2.la 
   >   -lz -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm   /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls   -o testSAX testSAX.o ./libxml2.la  -lz
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -liconv -lm   libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -o testSAX testSAX.o  ./.libs/libxml2.a
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -ldl -lz /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libiconv.a
   >   -lm libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -o testRelax testRelax.o 
   >   ./.libs/libxml2.a
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -ldl -lz /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libiconv.a
   >   -lm libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -o xmlcatalog xmlcatalog.o 
   >   ./.libs/libxml2.a
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -ldl -lz /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libiconv.a
   >   -lm libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -o testSchemas testSchemas.o 
   >   ./.libs/libxml2.a
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -ldl -lz /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libiconv.a
   >   -lm libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pedantic -W -Wformat -Wunused -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wcomment -Wtrigraphs -Wformat -Wchar-subscripts -Wuninitialized -Wparentheses -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wredundant-decls -o xmllint xmllint.o  ./.libs/libxml2.a
   >   -L/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -ldl -lz /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libiconv.a
   >   -lm ./..libs/libxml2.a(/.xmlIO.o):libs In function `xmlGzfileOpenW':
   >   //tmp/libxml2.aeasy_install-(Y2MKTgxmlIO.o/):lxml
   >   -2.3/In build/function tmp/`libxml2xmlGzfileOpenW-':
   >   2.7.8//xmlIO.c:tmp1247/:easy_install -Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/undefined libxml2-reference2.7.8/xmlIO.c:1247
   >   :to  undefined`gzopen64' 
   >   ./reference.libs/libxml2.a( xmlIO.o):
   >   In functionto 
   >   ``xmlGzfileOpen_real':gzopen64'
   >
   > /./tmp./libs/easy_installlibxml2.a-(xmlIO.oY2MKTg):/lxml-
   >   In 2.3function/build
   >   /tmp/`libxml2xmlGzfileOpen_real':
   >   -/2.7.8tmp//xmlIO.ceasy_install:1175-Y2MKTg/:lxml-
   >   2.3/build/undefinedtmp /referencelibxml2-2.7.8 /toxmlIO.c
   >   :`1175: gzopen64undefined'  reference
   >   to `gzopen64' collect2: collect2: ld
   >   returned 1 exit status ld returned 1
   >   exit status make[2]: *** [testRelax]
   >   Error 1 make[2]: *** Waiting for
   >   unfinished jobs.... make[2]: ***
   >   [testSAX] Error 1
   >   .././.libs/libslibxml2.a/(libxml2.axmlIO.o(xmlIO.o))::
   >   In function` In function
   >   `xmlGzfileOpenW'xmlGzfileOpenW':: /
   >   tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg//tmp/lxmleasy_install--Y2MKTg/lxml-2.32.3//build/tmp/buildlibxml2-2.7.8//xmlIO.ctmp:/libxml2-1247:
   >   undefined reference to`
   >   2.7.8gzopen64/xmlIO.c:1247:
   >   undefined'  .reference/ .to
   >   libs/`gzopen64libxml2.a'
   >   (./.xmlIO.olibs/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o)): :
   >   In Infunction function`
   >   xmlGzfileOpen_real '`:
   >   xmlGzfileOpen_real/':
   >   tmp//tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTgeasy_install-/Y2MKTg/lxml-lxml2.3-2.3//build/tmp/build/libxml2tmp/libxml2--2.7.82.7.8/xmlIO.c:/1175:xmlIO.c
   >   :1175: undefinedundefined  reference
   >   reference toto  ``gzopen64'
   >   gzopen64'collect2: ld returned 1 exit
   >   status
   >
   > collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   >   ./.libs/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In
   >   function `xmlGzfileOpenW':
   >   /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2-2.7.8/xmlIO.c:1247:
   >   undefined reference to`gzopen64'
   >   ./.libs/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In
   >   function `xmlGzfileOpen_real':
   >   /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2-2.7.8/xmlIO.c:1175:
   >   undefined reference to`gzopen64'
   >   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   >   make[2](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Install_Guide#Install_Python): *** [testSchemas] Error 1
   >   make[2](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Install_Guide#Install_Python):**  [xmlcatalog] Error 1
   >   make[2](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Install_Guide#Install_Python):  **[xmllint] Error 1
   >   make[2](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Install_Guide#Install_Python): Leaving directory
   >   `/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2-2.7.8'
   >   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   >   make[1]: Leaving directory`
   >   /tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/build/tmp/libxml2-2.7.8'
   >   make: *** [all] Error 2 Traceback
   >   (most recent call last):   File
   >   "/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7",
   >   line 8, in 
   >       load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11',
   >   'console_scripts',
   >   'easy_install-2.7')()   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 1712, in main   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 1700, in with_ei_usage   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 1716, in    File
   >   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py",
   >   line 152, in setup
   >       dist.run_commands()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py",
   >   line 953, in run_commands
   >       self.run_command(cmd)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py",
   >   line 972, in run_command
   >       cmd_obj.run()   File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 211, in run   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 446, in easy_install   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 476, in install_item   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 655, in install_eggs   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 930, in build_and_install   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
   >   line 919, in run_setup   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py",
   >   line 62, in run_setup   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py",
   >   line 105, in run   File
   >   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py",
   >   line 64, in    File
   >   "setup.py", line 130, in 
   >   File
   >   "/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/setupinfo.py",
   >   line 56, in ext_modules   File
   >   "/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/buildlibxml.py",
   >   line 311, in build_libxml2xslt   File
   >   "/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/buildlibxml.py",
   >   line 253, in cmmi   File
   >   "/tmp/easy_install-Y2MKTg/lxml-2.3/buildlibxml.py",
   >   line 236, in call_subprocess
   >   Exception: Command "make -j6" returned
   >   code 2

there was considerably more, and if you are interested you can check it out [here](http://pastebin.com/gXdMVHdP)

**I have tried** several other methods of installation. including @agilevic's which returned an error virtually identical to the one above. Most others install effortlessly, but all fail on `from lxml import etree`

Why not use a `yum`? Well, I was able to install lxml effortlessly through `yum install python-lxml`, but that was centOs' default installation of python2.4. At this point it is probably easier to retool my existing project to work with 2.4. In the long run, however, I would truly like to resolve this issue. For myself, and anyone else who may encounter a similar problem in the future.

Comment: "There was considerably more, but this was the error message it ended with." - We need more output, for starters the actual error message from `make`. Also, check the versions of libxml and libxslt.

Comment: @delnan, I have included more of the error, but its over 1000 lines and I dont feel it is entirely relevant to the question, as I am able to install lxml through other means.

Comment: do you have python-devel installed?

Comment: @Corey, I believe so. but I Cannot confirm this until I return to the office tomorrow morning. I may be able to ssh into the dev machine later, but for now I have dinner to make.

Comment: @Corey, I can confirm that I do indeed have python-devel installed.

Comment: Your python-devel is most likely for python 2.4 installation, not your 2.7 custom installation. How did you install 2.7?

Comment: through `yum`. Meaning, for 2.4, of course. Good catch. I'll check it out in the morning when I arrive at the office. wanted to start the bounty before bed, thanks, i'll let you kow.

Comment: @Keith, I do not believe python-devel is the issues. `import disutils` work fine according to http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gribble/index.php?title=Supybot_Install_Guide#Install_Python is a good way to test. I have found other ways to test and all echo the same message. Including some on SO, however, I still haven't found python-devel to isntall for 2.7 if I needed to. I can .rpms for 2.6 but am not able to find the source files anywhere.

Comment: Try [this one](ftp://ftp.pycopia.org/pub/python/RHEL51/python2.7-2.7.1-1TH.src.rpm) and see how it goes.

Comment: `rpm -i python2.7-2.7.1-1TH.src.rpm` returns
`error: cannot create %sourcedir /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES`, not being used to rpm's, I am not sure the easy way to fix this

Comment: What happens if you try to import one of the other etree implementations?  Particularly, cElementTree which is also a C library with python bindings.  `import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree`; if you get an error perhaps it will be helpful to get it from a different angle.  Good luck!  Sounds very frustrating.

Comment: @Rhichard, it imports flawlessly. So much for that different angle. This is very frustrating. Thanks for the idea, I'm all out of them at this point so everything helps.

Comment: @matchew if it's any consolation, i've been driven up the wall by lxml installs in the past (although sadly not in the same way as you, so it doesn't help), which ultimately resulted in me switching to cElementTree, which is bonkers fast (though lacks good xpath support in the standard distro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your libxslt do not have `exsltMathXpathCtxtRegister` remove it, and manually install a newer version (1.1.26 should work fine).

An older version of lxml may work too, try with `easy_install lxml==2.2.8`

Comment: interesting, i like this idea. I tried `sudo yum remove libxslt.i386 libxslt.x86_64 libxslt-devel.i386 libxslt-devel.x86_64` and it wanted to remove over 100 other packages, such as gnome-mount, gnome-desktop, system-config-bind, gnome-terminal, and other important sounding things. Should this concern me. I am rather unfamiliar with `yum`, however, `easy_install lxml==2.2.8` did solve my issue. I'd still like to get 2.3 working, but if worse comes to worse this will work. Best answer so far.

Comment: You only need to remove the development packages. Also if you are not very familiar with CentOS you may try to use ActivePython and its own package manager. It come with a lot of stuff built in, and there are a lot of libraries precompiled in their site.(available through ppm)

Comment: Okay, tried that and was unable to get libxslt-devel to install without also installing a newer version of libxslt. I'd still like to get lxml 2.3 installed, but lxml 2.2.8 is now installed flawlessly and doing everything I want it too. This may just be the answer I need to accept after close to 20hrs.

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/opt/xslt ; make install` after unpacking the library. Then try to install lxml with `CFLAGS='-I/opt/xslt/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/xslt/lib' easy_install lxml`

Answer (score 2):

A word to future googlers - I arrived here with the same symptom, but a sufficiently recent packaged version of  libxslt installed (1.1.26). Took about 10 minutes before I realised I *also* had an ancient version in my path, (installed with the `casapy` astronomy package).

Moral of the story: run a `locate libxslt` to find old versions, and check against your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`! (Of course, this applies to any library conflict in general).

Comment: thanks for keeping this updated. I never have had time to get back to this project, or have I done much work on this specific server recently.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your output it looks like the linker output an error:
`undefined reference to gzopen64`

That error bubbled up into `lxml-2.3/buildlibxml.py", line 236, in call_subprocess`, which bubbled up again into `make -j6`

I found a thread here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15524 that had the same compiler error.   With a suggestion

> You may the i586 version of the zlib delegate library installed. You may need to install the 64-bit version of zlib and zlib-devel.

And the OP of that thread later commented:

> What i did now is downloading the source from zlib and compiled it into local environment.
>   /usr/local/includes and such.
>   recompiled all plugins
>   and compiled ImageMagick again.
>
> Now it works. Many thanks  :D

So, I'd suggest re-installing zlib and zlib-devel, and then try to install lxml again.

Comment: I like this suggestion, as ultimately this is the same line I had an issue will. -j6, from what I understand just allows make to you all 6 cpus. I tried turning the -j flag off and even throwing a -d, but the error persisted. I think I will try this tomorrow morning. However, I still do not understand how I can do a manual install and install a non working copy of lxml.

Comment: regrettably this did not solve my problem. I had the correct version of zlib installed, but I did need to install the zlib-devel package.

Answer (score 0):

You best best may be compiling LibXML2 and LibXSLT from sources. Assuming the prefix for your installation should be the same as your custom Python, which appears to be /usr/local, here's how (there may be newer version of the software so, check that first):

```
wget http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxml2-sources-2.7.7.tar.gz
gzip -dc libxml2-sources-2.7.7.tar.gz | tar xvf -
cd libxml2-2.7.7
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
wget http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz
gzip -dc libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz | tar xvf -
cd libxslt-1.1.26
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

If the above does not compile, there may be other dependencies that you should try to satisfy from yum packages, typically these would be certain libraries and/or *-devel packages with missing header files.

Once that's done either

```
easy_install lxml
```

or

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: yeah, I had tried that last week before posting this question. Which is then what lead me to try `STATIC_DEPS=true`, but I'll give this another shot and let you know how it went. Thanks

Comment: This was what I had tried initially, minus the `--prefix=/usr/local`. It failed originally, and I installed both through `yum` I believe this to be appropriate. These are not particular to python, just so long as they are installed. `libxml2` fails on `sudo make` with the `following make[2]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/matt/libxml2-2.7.2'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/matt/libxml2-2.7.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If you have installed the libxslt and libxml2 from yum packages, there is no need to be compiling them but you need respective devel packages with headers. In my own experience this rarely worked. Best to uninstalle if proceeding with building from sources.

Your other option is compile both libraries from sources into the /usr/local. As a side note, the compilation needs not be done as sudo but make install does. Finally, the make errors are not meaningful. For detailed instruction on building from sources, read INSTALL files and see ./configure --help.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have libxslt-dev and libxml2-dev installed on your machine (you can do this with yum I guess); lxml won't build without them.

Comment: -1. I generally refrain from handing out -1's on my own question, but this was clearly stated in my question that I do and have.

Comment: Read over that part, my bad, but my suggestion actually is to install libxslt-dev and libxml-dev using yum and compiling python-lxml from source after that. You can install those systemwide since they are not bound to a certain python version. Just trying to help out...

Comment: I understand. And It was with great regret I gave the -1, but after spending the past 6hrs on this only to have the first solution offered be not only one of the first things listed in the lxml installation instructions, but also one of the first things I said in my question I had to hand out the -1. Dont take it personally, I do appreciate the help. That was the initial way I tried to install lxml and is indeed one of the main reasons I know both are installed.