# Import lxml failed on CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Tags: python, gcc, centos, lxml

I updatd python on centos6.7 to python2.7.3,and made the new version as default. Then I used `sudo yum install python-lxml` to install python-lxml. It shows

`package python-lxml-2.2.3-1.1.el6.x86_64 has been installed and is the newest,there is nothing to do`

But when I use python (the default 2.7.3) `python` and `import lxml`,error happens as follow
[ImportError: No module named lxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PyPf.jpg).However when i use the older version python like `/usr/bin/python2.6` and `import lxml`,no error happens. The lxml works on the older version python.

What's the problem?

I tried many other ways:

**1.** Use pip to install lxml `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install lxml`,but errors happen

`src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:237975: error：expected ‘)’ before ‘value’`

`Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

```
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c
```

`/tmp/xmlXPathInitB69jpu.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitB69jpu.o`

```
/tmp/xmlXPathInitB69jpu.c:1:26: error：libxml/xpath.h：no such file or directory

Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`Command /usr/bin/python -c "import` 
`setuptools;__file__='/home/zhoulipeng/software/lxml-3.4.4/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-VIpDJ1-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1` [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGZuK.jpg)

It seems libxml2 isn't installed, so I install all the dependences,`sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel`,it shows:

```
package libxml2-devel-2.7.6-20.el6.x86_64 has been installed and is the newest
package libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64 has been installed and is the newest
package python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 has been installed and is the newest
```

That means I already installed the package libxml2.

**2.** Install lxml from source code

When I build the source code with `sudo python setup.py build` ,it failed with
`src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:201156:error:expected ')'before'__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_xslt_doc_loader'`
 `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Can someone help me? thank you.

Comment: **Do not mess with the default system python on a CentOS/RedHat system**. You will only cause horrible problems (up to and including the breaking of `yum` entirely. Different python versions look for modules in different places. The packages are all built for the CentOS 6 version of python (2.6.6). Your python isn't looking in the same places.

Comment: so what should i do if i want the lxml works with the updated python version 2.7.3 (default)? now the lxml works with the older python2.6 but not with the updated python2.7.3. thank you.

Comment: You get to install python modules manually using your version of python and not use any system packages. You should also look into the python Software Collection Libraries (SCLs) as they might have what you want in an officially packaged manner.

Comment: Well, I try to install the lxml from source code. As the default version of python is the updated version 2.7.3, so i use "sudo python setup.py build" , but errors happen "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"( as mentioned before). However gcc is already installed in the centos server , so now i don't konw what can i do (when using "pip",errors happen too). I'll check the python Software Collection Libraries later, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `gcc` is installed? Because it doesn't look like it (or something else went very wrong). Can you run `gcc --help` and get the help output correctly? Where is `gcc` installed? What does `command -v gcc` say? What is the `$PATH` under `sudo`? (i.e. What does `sudo 'echo $PATH'` output?)

Comment: Thank you and i’ll check it tomorrow, very sorry to trouble you so much

Comment: Hello, i check all that you said. when i run "gcc --help", the help output shows correctly, when run "command -v gcc",the result is "/usr/bin/gcc".But when i run "$PATH" under sudo, it shows "-bash: /usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin: no such file or directory", and when run "sudo 'echo $PATH' " under normal user,it shows "sudo: echo $PATH: can not find the command", is there something wrong?

Comment: You meant `sudo -s 'echo $PATH'` or `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`. `$PATH` isn't a valid binary/script and neither is `echo '$PATH'` (that's a valid command at the shell but not a binary/script itself).

Comment: But `gcc` is working so you get to look at the build/configure logs to find out what failed.

Comment: Haha..., i think i solve the problem, when i read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417881/still-cannot-properly-install-lxml-2-3-for-python-but-at-least-2-2-8-works?rq=1 , so i install package libxml2-devel.i686 then rebuild the source code of lxml and install. It works!!!  The command "import lxml" works both in python2.7.3 and python2.6. Thank you so much and wish you all the best.

Answer (score 1):

The yum installed lxml in pythons 2.6 path. You need to search for an rpm for python 2.7 or build your own rpm.

That is if whoever provided your python 27, also built a rpm for lxml.

If you installed python27 via software collections from redhat, you could also try:

```
yum install python27-python-pip -y
scl enable python27 bash
pip install lxml

# python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun  9 2015, 19:27:51)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'am not clear about "You need to search for an rpm for python 2.7 or build your own rpm", i tried to build lxml from source but failed. Thank you.

Comment: OK, that was me trying to tell you that you need a rpm from whoever built and distributed the python 2.7 rpms. We could try to build a rpm if you don't have that. First, how did you installed the newer version of python? From RedHat scl repos?

Comment: I build the newer version of python from source code, and set the newer version as default. when i type "python" in shell, it shows the version of python that i installed.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the official packages for python27?

Comment: when i use "yum install python27-python-pip -y", it shows: No package python27-python-pip available. What should i do?

Comment: And i download the source code of python2.7.3 from the official website, for I see many blogs about updating the python version  download the package first. Thank you.

Comment: Haha..., i solve the problem after i install package libxml2-devel.i686 and it works. Thank you for your help and wish you all the best.

Comment: Anyway, you should try to use the official python27 from redhat scl.